# How can I run my iOS project in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have created an iOS single view application on XCODE. Can I open that project in Xamarin Studio?If yes then how?

I have checked the project directory which is created on XCODE. It shows .xcodeproj.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't.

I suggest you go read up on how to create an application using Xamarin.iOS at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/

P.S. Once you've done that you could trywhat you can do however is create a single view application in Xamarin Studio and import the Storyboard you create in Xcode.